# What is the correct format of connectionstring for Azure Service Bus when using Managed Identity for my App Service?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, nservicebus, azure-appservice

I have this App Service in Azure running as a Web Job. The application is a former Windows Service built using NServiceBus and I have been reconfiguring it to work in Azure.

The application is using AzureServiceBusTransport and I have my Azure Service Bus with a queue set up.

I got it working... when I am using a Shared Access Key configured in my connectionstring like this;

```
"ConnectionString": "Endpoint=sb://MYNAMESPACE.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=***"
```

To make it work with Managed Identity I have reconfigured in my NServiceBus EndpointConfiguration with;

```
transport.CustomTokenCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential());
```

I also changed my connectionstring to the following;

```
"ConnectionString": "Endpoint=sb://MYNAMESPACE.servicebus.windows.net/;Authentication=ManagedIdentity"
```

But when I try to use Managed Identity instead I get the following exception;

ArgumentException: The value 'Endpoint=sb://MYNAMESPACE.servicebus.windows.net/;Authentication=ManagedIdentity' is not a well-formed Service Bus fully qualified namespace.

MYNAMESPACE is obviously correct when I use Shared Access Key but not when I use Managed Identity?

We do have an Azure Function that CAN use Managed Identity and is in that case using;

```
"ConnectionString": "Endpoint=sb://MYNAMESPACE.servicebus.windows.net/;Authentication=ManagedIdentity"
```

Comment: It should be possible to achieve using MSI from App Service to Azure Service Bus, like this github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-msi-servicebus-dotnet. But it seems I can not configure it this way with NServiceBus or I am missing something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just ran into the same issue with NServiceBus. Instead of:

```
"ConnectionString": "Endpoint=sb://MYNAMESPACE.servicebus.windows.net/;Authentication=ManagedIdentity"
```

just set:

```
"ConnectionString": "MYNAMESPACE.servicebus.windows.net"
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I did try that as well but receieved another exception and neglected that was a correct exception for me running locally in visual studio.

Comment: For a bit more information on the answer you can refer to this [thread](https://discuss.particular.net/t/nservicebus-in-app-service-using-managed-identity-for-connect-to-azure-service-bus/2815/2?u=tmasternak) on NServiceBus forum